# express.js api request hangs when app.use uses imported middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, es6-modules

I am trying to create a simple rest api with express.js. I am using babel so I can use es6 syntax.  Originally I had my route logic in server.js and it all worked fine.  I wanted to restructure my routes and put them into external files and then import them into my server.js. I used `app.use('/', routes)` after import to run them in server.js.  I cannot get this to work.  When I check the routes in postman it just hangs.  I have spent a lot of time on stackoverflow and reading other articles trying to figure out how to import and then use external files in my server.js file.  It seems like it should be simple but I cannot get it to work.  Also, I tried doing the same thing with require() and exports.module before I switched to babel and it still did not work.

#### server.js

I want to import my routes from routes/index.js file here and call it with `app.use('/', routes);` file is below.

```
/*
 Name: server.js
 Notes: file that starts backend.
*/

//Imports
import express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import routes from './routes/index';

//Init Express
const app = express();

//Set Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Parses json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//  Connect all our routes to our application
app.use('/', routes);


//Spins up Node Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port} `);
});
```

#### index.js

I want to export my routes function from here routes/index.js.

```
/*
  Name: index.js
  Notes: export routes function here
*/

import express from 'express';
const app = express();

function routes(){
    app.get('/test', function(req, res,next) {
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Connected!' });
   });
}


export default routes
```

### Folder Structure

This is my folder structure for the files involved.

```
server.js
|
routes
     |
     index.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong here.

First, `app.use('/', routes);` is just wrong.  The way you have `route` defined, it is just a normal function (not middleware) that you would call as a regular function in order for it to then register your route with `app.get()`.

Second, you're creating two separate `app` objects and the one in `index.js` is not connected to a running server so it does nothing.

The usual way to encapsulate routes in a separate file is to use a router.

```
/*
  Name: index.js
  Notes: export router here
*/

import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', function(req, res,next) {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Connected!' });
});


export default router
```

And, then modify server.js to use that router by just changing names to match and hooking the router into the app with `app.use(router)`:

```
*
 Name: server.js
 Notes: file that starts backend.
*/

//Imports
import express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import router from './routes/index';

//Init Express
const app = express();

//Set Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Parses json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//  Connect all our routes to our application
app.use(router);


//Spins up Node Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port} `);
});
```

---

If you didn't want to use a separate router (not sure why), then you could just pass the `app` object to the `router()` function and just call it as a normal function.

```
/*
 Name: server.js
 Notes: file that starts backend.
*/

//Imports
import express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import routes from './routes/index';

//Init Express
const app = express();

//Set Port Number
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Parses json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//  Connect all our routes to our application
routes(app);


//Spins up Node Server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port} `);
});

/*
  Name: index.js
  Notes: export routes function here
*/

// function to initialize some routes on the pass-in app object
function routes(app){
    app.get('/test', function(req, res,next) {
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Connected!' });
   });
}


export default routes
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!! I knew it had to be something simple.  I think what was initially getting me was declaring another instance of express.  I will say I have been confused from other threads that have said declaring express.router() is deprecated.  That is why I didn't initially do that.

Comment: @DavidSanders - Where did you see something that said `express.Router()` is deprecated?  It's fully described in both the [Express 4.0 doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router) and the [Express 5.0 (alpha) doc](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.router).  Also, this is the supported way we've been doing it in Express 4.x for years now.

Comment: @jrfriend00 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565167/app-router-is-deprecated-on-simple-website . Look at answer.  I have seen lots of this on the web.  It could be refering to something completely different though.  I am new to this framework.

Comment: @DavidSanders - That is something completely different.  That is referring to `app.router` and has nothing to do with `express.Router()`. And, in fact, `app.router` is coming back in Express 5 to expose the base level router that the `app` object creates automatically.  You can read about that and other Express 5 changes [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/whats-new-in-expressjs-5-0#toc-changes-and-improvements).